# Как корректно настроить даты и устранить перекрывающиеся интервалы в SQL-запросе для таблицы с начальными и конечными датами?

Tags: sql, база-данных, bigquery

У меня возникла проблема с составлением SQL-запроса для корректировки дат в таблице. У меня есть следующая таблица "table_main":

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

Моя цель - корректировать даты таким образом, чтобы устранить пересечение дат между записями, сохраняя при этом последовательность начальных дат. Я использовал следующий SQL-запрос:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.start_date <= t2.end_date THEN DATE_ADD(t2.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ELSE t1.start_date
    END AS start_date,
    t1.end_date,
    t1.industry,
    t1.exclusion_rate,
    t1.suppliers
FROM 
    table_main AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    table_main AS t2
ON 
    t1.industry = t2.industry
    AND t1.suppliers = t2.suppliers
    AND t1.start_date <= t2.end_date
    AND t1.end_date >= t2.start_date
    AND (t1.start_date <> t2.start_date OR t1.end_date <> t2.end_date)
```

Однако полученный результат содержит некорректные даты начала. Например, полученный результат выглядит следующим образом:

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2022-01-16 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| **2022-02-02** | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

Я хотел бы получить следующий результат:

| start_date | end_date | name | rate | id_sup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name1 | 1 | SUP1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 32 | SUP3 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name3 | 15 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name4 | 54 | SUP2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | name5 | 43 | SUP1 |
| 2022-01-16 | 2023-02-01 | name6 | 64 | SUP1 |
| **2022-01-01** | 2023-01-15 | name6 | 43 | SUP1 |

Можете ли вы помочь мне разобраться, как составить SQL-запрос, который даст мне нужный результат? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Собрать все даты в один список с весами +1 начало, -1 конец. Посчитать сумму весов с накоплением. Оставить последовательные пары, где у меньшей сумма не ноль.